# running php file with pycharm and redis server

Tags: php, python-3.x, django, redis, pycharm

I am working on a django project which requires to run 2 php files.
One of the file must have access to the redis database that I configured in docker-compose file.
So, how do I run these php files and map redis database. I am using ubuntu os.

code is -

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST)) {
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $redis = new Redis();
    $redis->pconnect('redis'); // REDIS_HOST hast to be the same as in BBB_REDIS_HOST
    $redis->publish('chat', $message); // REDIS_CHANNEL hast to be the same as in BBB_REDIS_CHANNEL
    echo "Message published\n";
```

the error I am facing is -

```
127.0.0.1:49496 [500]: POST /sendChatMessage.php - syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/dir/Desktop/BigBlueButton-liveStreaming-master/examples/sendChatMessage.php on line 8
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not use the cli version of PHP for this, as usual?

Comment: @NicoHaase I have updated the question with the error I am getting.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: there's a syntax error in the PHP file. Please add a closing `}` to resolve this